# Change jquery function triggered by drop down

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to resolve this for hours, but with no success. I also searched the existing questions, but did not find the correct answer :-/

I currently have a drop down on my website which triggers a function to change the active language on the sessions table. What I was trying to do is to get rid of the ugly drop down and replace it with a fancybox to change the language. All works fine except of triggering the change function and I would need your help on changing the jquery code in order to to the same function as the drop down does, but now triggered by a text link. Here is the old drop down:

Dropdown:

```
<form id="language-selection-form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/home/save_lang_change">
            <?php $lang = $this->session->userdata('language'); ?>
            <select id="language-selection" name="language-selection">
                <option value="spanish" <?php echo (!empty($lang) && $lang == 'spanish') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Espanol</option>
                <option value="german" <?php echo (!empty($lang) && $lang == 'german') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Deutsch</option>
                <option value="english" <?php echo (!empty($lang) && $lang == 'english') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>English</option>
            </select>
        </form>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var http_host_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#language-selection').change(function(){
        /*var lang = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: http_host_url + "index.php/home/save_lang_change",
            data: {
                lang: lang
            },
            success: function(html){
                console.log(html);
            }
        }) */

        jQuery('#language-selection-form').submit();

    })
})</script>
```

now, the new script would be:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#lang_change"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>app/css/images/flags/es.png" /> Español</a>
    <div id="lang_change" style="width:200px;display: none;">
                <h3>Choose your language:</h3><br/>
                <p align="center"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>app/css/images/flags/es.png" />&nbsp;Español</p>
                <p align="center"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>app/css/images/flags/gb.png" />&nbsp;English</p>
                <p align="center"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>app/css/images/flags/de.png" />&nbsp;Deutsch</p>
    </div>
```

but of course, it does not trigger the jquery function.

here is the function in the home.php controller:

```
function save_lang_change(){

    //echo $_POST['language-selection']  . " hjkh ff";
    $lang = $_POST['language-selection'];
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->session->set_userdata("language", $lang);
    //echo $this->session->userdata("language");
    redirect(base_url());

 }
```

Any idea on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery/javascript is unneccessary. I have modified the home.php controller to have a function for each language:

```
     function save_lang_change_es(){

    $lang = spanish;
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->session->set_userdata("language", $lang);
    //echo $this->session->userdata("language");
    redirect(base_url());

 }

 function save_lang_change_en(){

    $lang = english;
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->session->set_userdata("language", $lang);
    //echo $this->session->userdata("language");
    redirect(base_url());

 }

 function save_lang_change_de(){

    $lang = german;
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->session->set_userdata("language", $lang);
    //echo $this->session->userdata("language");
    redirect(base_url());

 }
```

and changed the links as follows:

```
<div id="lang_change" style="width:200px;display: none;">
                <h3>Choose your language:</h3><br/>
                <p align="center"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/home/save_lang_change_es"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>app/css/images/flags/es.png" />&nbsp;Español</a></p>
                <p align="center"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/home/save_lang_change_en"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>app/css/images/flags/gb.png" />&nbsp;English</a></p>
                <p align="center"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/home/save_lang_change_de"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>app/css/images/flags/de.png" />&nbsp;Deutsch</a></p>
    </div>
```

now, each link calls its own function and the language switch works :)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
jQuery('#language-selection').change(function(){
```

to

```
jQuery("#lang_change p").click(function(){
```

Comment: Thanks Mooseman, this would enable the click event, which brings me one step forward. How would I indicate the language? Would I use an <a href="???">Language here</a>? Thanks :)

Comment: You already have an image there inside the `<p>`. No `<a>` is needed, because jQuery picks up the click event. Just add text alongside the image if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var http_host_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
function changeLang(lang){
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url: http_host_url + "index.php/home/save_lang_change",
                data: {
                    lang: lang
                },
                success: function(html){
                    console.log(html);
                }
            }) ;

            jQuery('#language-selection-form').submit();

        }
</script>
<a class="fancybox" href="#lang_change"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>app/css/images/flags/es.png" /> Español</a>
    <div id="lang_change" style="width:200px;display: none;">
                <h3>Choose your language:</h3><br/>
                <p align="center" onclick="changeLang('es');"><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>app/css/images/flags/es.png" />&nbsp;Español</p>
                <p align="center" changeLang('en');><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>app/css/images/flags/gb.png" />&nbsp;English</p>
                <p align="center" changeLang('de');><img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>app/css/images/flags/de.png" />&nbsp;Deutsch</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: On click on the first <p> it reloads the page, but nothing seems to change. the second and third p element are not clickable. I added the onclick="" to the second and third p element as you show in the first one, but still, nothing happens... I then changed it so there is a <p align="center"><a onclick="changeLang('xx');">Language here</a></p>, but still not working :-(

Comment: Can you change p element to anchors and call function using href="javascript:funtion();"?